# Select all rows with one-to-many condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select all rows in tblAAA that satisfy a condition.

A tblAAA has 1 or more tblBBB.
A tblBBB has 1 tblCCC.
I want to update all rows in tblAAA where **all of its** tblBBB has a tblCCC where tblCCC.status = 1.

Please see provided image.

Really greatful for help, I have been staring at this for two hours but have no clue.

Edit:
One thing I did try was this:

```
select * from tblAAA
inner join tblBBB
on tblAAA.tblAAA_id = tblBBB.tblAAA_id
inner join tblCCC
on tblBBB.tblCCC_id = tblCCC.tblCCC_id
where tblCCC.status = 1;
```

But that does not work, because this gives all tblAAA where at least one tblBBB satisfies the condition.

[image]

Comment: Would appreciate if you tell me why you downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote (yet), but I suppose someone thinks it looks like you want us to do your homework.

Comment: Ok, well that would be wrong. I want to understand how to do it, and learn how to do it myself. I could post stuff I have tried, but I feel that would just confuse you.

Comment: Your question is confusing, and the graphs don't really help.  It would be better to post some sample data and describe the result that you're looking for.

Comment: And please show us what you have tried. Otherwise this question looks like "Gimme teh codez!"

Comment: Ok, I will update the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the diagram is saying to return all rows from `tblAAA` that have a row in `tblBBB` but do not have a row that lead to `tblCCC.active= 0`, then:

rextester: http://rextester.com/OBOE63409

```
create table tblAAA (AAA_Id int, status bit);
insert into tblAAA values (1,1),(2,0),(3,1);

create table tblBBB (BBB_id int identity(1,1), AAA_id int, CCC_id int);
insert into tblBBB values (1,1),(2,1),(2,2);

create table tblCCC (CCC_id int, active bit);
insert into tblCCC values (1,1),(2,0);

/* AAA_Id 1 has only one row in tblBBB and leads to tblCCC.active=1 */
/* AAA_Id 2 has only two rows in tblBBB and one leads to tblCCC.active=0 */
/* AAA_Id 3 has no row in tblBBB -- not returned */

/* using the inner join from tblAAA to tblBBB 
  requires that AAA_id have at least one row in tblBBB */

select a.AAA_id, a.status
  from tblAAA as a
    inner join tblBBB as b on a.AAA_id = b.AAA_id
  where not exists (
    select 1
      from tblBBB as b
        inner join tblCCC as c on b.CCC_id=c.CCC_id
        where b.AAA_id = a.AAA_ID
          and c.active=0
  )
  group by a.AAA_id, a.status
  /* if AAA_id must have at least n rows in tblBBB 
     that lead to tblCCC.active=1
     then using having count(b.Id) > n */
  --having count(b.Id)>1
```

To update all `tblAAA` where all of its `tblBBB` has a `tblCCC` where `tblCCC.active = 1`.

```
update a
  set a.status=1
  from tblAAA as a
    inner join tblBBB as b on a.AAA_id = b.AAA_id
  where not exists (
    select 1
      from tblBBB as b
        inner join tblCCC as c on b.CCC_id=c.CCC_id
        where b.AAA_id = a.AAA_ID
          and c.active=0
    )
```

or

```
update a
  set a.status=1
  from tblAAA as a
  where not exists (
    select 1
      from tblBBB as b
        inner join tblCCC as c on b.CCC_id=c.CCC_id
        where b.AAA_id = a.AAA_ID
          and c.active=0
    )
    and exists (
      select 1
        from tblBBB as b
          where b.AAA_id = a.AAA_ID
          )
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used?

Comment: @jarlh same as using `select distinct` in this instance. Leads into contingency for `having count(b.Id)` depending on how the diagram is to be interpreted.

Comment: I'll test this, get back to you soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
update tblAAA
set status = 'new status'
where AAA_ID in (
    select a.AAA_ID
    from tblAAA a
    join tblBBB b on a.AAA_ID = b.AAA_ID
    join tblCCC c on c.CCC_ID = b.CCC_ID
    group by a.AAA_ID, a.status
    having sum(case c.active when 1 then 1 else 0 end) = count(c.active)
)
```